# What is implementation of &#39;menu2&#39

Tags: javascript, css, html

In the following drop down menu there are java script functions calling by `onmouseover="openelement(&#39;menu2&#39;)" , onmouseover="openelement(&#39;menu3&#39;)"` etc.I can't understand what this `&#39;menu2&#39 , &#39;menu3&#39;` is.Can someone please explain me this. The whole program as following.

Drop down Menu CSS & JS

```
    <!--The CSS code.-->
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">

            #nav {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            #nav li {
                list-style: none;
                float: left;
            }

            #nav li a {
                display: block;
                margin: 0 1px 0 0;
                padding: 4px 10px;
                width: 80px;
                background: lavender;
                color: black;
                text-align: center;
                text-decoration:none;
            }

            #nav li a:hover {
                background: grey;
            }

            #nav ul {
                position: absolute;
                visibility: hidden;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                border: 1px solid #ffffff
            }

            #nav  ul li a{
                    position: relative;
                    margin: 0;
                    padding: 5px 10px;
                    width: 80px;
                    text-align: left;
                    background: lavender;
                    color: #000000;
                }   

            #nav li ul li {
                clear: both;
            }
    </style>
    <!--The end of the CSS code.-->

    <!--The Javascript menu code.-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //variables' declaration

        var timeout = 500;
        var timer   = 0;
        var item    = 0;

        //function for opening of submenu elements
        function openelement(num)
        {    
            keepsubmenu()
            //checks whether there is an open submenu and makes it invisible
            if(item){ item.style.visibility = 'hidden';}
                //shows the chosen submenu element
                item = document.getElementById(num);
                item.style.visibility = 'visible';
        }

        // function for closing of submenu elements
        function closeelement()
        {
            //closes the open submenu elements and loads the timer with 500ms
            timer = window.setTimeout("if(item) item.style.visibility = 'hidden';",500);
        }

        //function for keeping the submenu loaded after the end of the 500 ms timer
        function keepsubmenu()
        {
            if(timer){
                window.clearTimeout(timer);
                timer = null;
            }
        }

        //hides the visualized menu after clicking outside of its area and expiring of the loaded timer
        document.onclick = closeelement;

    </script>
    <!--END of CSS code-->

</head>
<body>
    <!--HTML code for the menu -->
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="http://www.sci.sjp.ac.lk/lms/file.php/233/dropDownJs.html#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://www.sci.sjp.ac.lk/lms/file.php/233/dropDownJs.html#" onmouseover="openelement(&#39;menu2&#39;)" onmouseout="closeelement()">Tutorials</a>
            <ul id="menu2" onmouseover="keepsubmenu()" onmouseout="closeelement()" style="visibility: hidden; ">
                <li><a href="http://www.sci.sjp.ac.lk/lms/file.php/233/dropDownJs.html#">CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.sci.sjp.ac.lk/lms/file.php/233/dropDownJs.html#">Flash</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://www.sci.sjp.ac.lk/lms/file.php/233/dropDownJs.html#" onmouseover="openelement(&#39;menu3&#39;)" onmouseout="closeelement()">More</a>
            <ul id="menu3" onmouseover="keepsubmenu()" onmouseout="closeelement()">
               <li><a href="http://www.sci.sjp.ac.lk/lms/file.php/233/dropDownJs.html#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.sci.sjp.ac.lk/lms/file.php/233/dropDownJs.html#">Contact Us</a></li> 
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    <!--the end of the HTML code for the menu -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just an apostrophe, probably from a bad copy/paste. It can happen if you write your code in Word for example or you copy from a textarea that applies special formatting. What it should be is single quotes since the function expects a string.

```
"openelement('menu3')"
```

Comment: If this answers your question please validate it.

Answer (score 3):

39 is the ASCII code for apostrophe and `&#39;` is the syntax for inserting ASCII characters into HTML

this syntax is mostly used to insert characters that has meaning in HTML / JavaScript as is (and to prevent Cross Site Scripting attacks) - such as `<` and `>` characters

in your case you should replace the &#39; occurrences inside the event handlers with apostrophes (') so it acts as it should in Javascript

Comment: The code works as is (as far as this issue is considered): the Ascii apostrophe *may* be written as `&#39;` in HTML (when it is not used as an attribute value delimiter). The notation is converted to the apostrophe in HTML parsing, so the JavaScript interpreter sees the apostrophe. It is just *not useful* to escape it here (but it might result from the use of software that escapes apostrophes routinely).